# Surface Integral with vector field question?

Tags: vector-analysis, volume, vector-fields, surface-integrals

Let $V$ be a volume in $\mathbb{R}^3$ bounded by a simple closed piecewise-smooth surface $S$ with outward pointing normal vector $\mathbf{n}$. For which one of the following vector fields is the surface integral $\iint_S f\cdot\mathbf{n} \space dS$ equal to the volume of $V$?

**A:** $\mathbf{f}(\mathbf{r})=(1,1,1)$ 
**B:** $\mathbf{f}(\mathbf{r})=(2x,-y^2,2yz-z)$ 
**C:** $\mathbf{f}(\mathbf{r})=(z^2,y^2,1-2yz)$ 
**D:** $\mathbf{f}(\mathbf{r})=\frac{1}{2}(x,y,z)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: For the surface integral for outward pointing normal vector to be equal to volume, $ div F$ (divergence of the vector field) should be positive constant $1$ independent of $x, y, z$.

$\frac{\partial (2x)}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial (-y^2)}{\partial y} + \frac{\partial (2yz-z)}{\partial z}$ is the one that gives $1$.

$\\\int_V div F dv$ becomes $\int_V 1 dv = V$

Comment: Ahhh! Thank you very much, so in my case **B** is the vector field whose surface integral  is equal to the volume of $V$?

Comment: @B24Panther yes that is correct. In fact $2$ of them have no divergence and the other option also is a positive constant but not $1$.